# How to explain why branch + merge is better than continuous pull + push for branches multiple people are working on?

Tags: git

Let's say there is a branch that multiple developers are working on, called `TestBranch`

Now, there are two (main) ways of letting multiple people work on this branch. (There's rebasing too, but I'm ignoring that for now)

1:

- Developers make changes
- Before they push, they pull the latest changes from everyone else with a `git pull origin TestBranch` (or just `git pull`)
- Deal with any merge conflicts
- `git push origin TestBranch` (or just `git push`) so everyone else gets their changes

2:

- `git checkout -b MyBranch` (or a branch followed by checkout) to make their own personal branch to work in.
- When they have finished a sub-task, they do `git checkout TestBranch`
- `git pull` to get the latest changes on `TestBranch` (won't trigger any merge, since they haven't touched `TestBranch`, just a `fast-forward`),
- `git merge MyBranch`
- Deal with any merge conflicts
- `git push origin TestBranch` so everyone else gets their changes

The second method requires a bit more work overall, but the git history of option #1 is a nightmare to look at, especially with more than a couple developers. It's a massive field of lines criss-crossing, tons of nodes that aren't actual content, etc.

How do I explain this? Is there a good example, maybe a picture, something to say why doing #1 is a bad idea in the long run?

(Or if I'm wrong, feel free to tell me so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the following is my personal opinion and I know from experience that discussing git workflows can be a quite heated topic as some decisions are up to taste.

---

However, there are already a few (very common) branching strategies (workflows) to deal with this  and other Problems. [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows) has quite a nice overview of a few models.

For your specific problem, if you would like to have a clean git history and are working only on one branch, have you thought of doing `git pull --rebase` before `git push` (assuming you are working on `TestBranch`)? This would give you a 'nice' and straight commit history, without any overhead introduced (merge conflicts will need to be fixed anyway)

If people work on specific blocks (say new features or bugfixes), the introduction of a 'feature' or 'fix' branch is usually good idea, and similar to what you suggested in (2). This also adds a nice scope for commits, so when branches have a clear name (say `feature/tooltip`), you instantly know where too look for changes for that feature. The difference to your suggestion is that branches are not scoped by the user working on it, but more by the feature/fix it contains. So this might lead to multiple (but usually few, as these branches should be short-lived) developers working on one branch.

Also, if I understand your two approaches correctly, both methods will create the same amount of merge conflicts and branches, so I cannot see an improvement in (2).

Comment: Pull with rebase is the simplicity of #1 without awful commit history. It's honestly a good solution for cases where the branch would end up being very short lived. (Simple fixes, back-and-forth work on something without longer plans, etc). I'm trying to think if it could be problematic, but I don't see any immediate problem. Thanks! I've used it before but hadn't thought of it for this case.

Comment: The setup we have at my current workplace is a 'main' branch called `develop`, with a `git pull --rebase` - `git push` workflow for commits directly to the branch (usually short fixes/feaures). Bigger changes go into their own scoped branches. This is a very common workflow (called `gitflow`) and having worked with it for a while I too cannot see any problems, besides someone might not (fully!) understanding the concept of rebasing (which is admittedly not easy at first).

Comment: Is there a good way to argue *why* this kind of workflow is good? That is an important part of the original question. What common pitfalls it is avoiding? Or is the explanation already on Atlassian.

Comment: I highly recommend reading through the Atlassian article, however, I would argue that the biggest advantage is a very clean git history, making it easy to follow changes. 
As said above, the addition of topic-specific feature and fix branches also adds another level of scope (which usually means order in some sense). Depending on how you will merge the feature branches back (there are several options, the 'cleanest' probably being rebasing the branch onto `develop` and then a merge or squash commit into `develop`, this will lead to a very comprehensible log.